# Open webOS on Ubuntu only displays partial desktop

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, webos

I followed the [directions](https://github.com/openwebos/build-desktop) to build, install, and run Open webOS simulator for Ubuntu 12.04.  Unfortunately, when the display comes up, following `./run-luna-sysmgr.sh`, most of the webOS desktop is hidden (see image below).  The images I've seen of a successful install show the entire desktop displayed and filling the entire application window.

I've verified all of the dependencies in the instructions and repeated the build and install steps a few times, but the results are the same.  I also tried searching through the Open webOS website and Google, but was unable to find anything related to this particular problem. I even watched a few YouTube videos of the entire build, install, and run process from beginning to end.  I still could not identify any issues with my own process.

[image: screen shot of Ubuntu desktop running webOS]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Switching from 64-bit Ubuntu to 32-bit fixed it for me.